# Where can I find CrackMes for beginners?

Tags: crackme

I'm interested in learning. Where can I find CrackMes for beginners? Especially ones with answers.

Comment: sorry, this kind of questions is not a good fit for this site.

Comment: crackmes.de is a good site, it's down currently though...

Comment: this seems like a perfectly reasonable question to me [and perfect for this forum], @IgorSkochinsky?

Comment: @rustyMagnet see [here](/help/dont-ask). if you disagree, feel free to open a discussion on meta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try these two links, they are full of resources :

1. https://johannesbader.ch/projects/solutions-to-crackmes/
2. https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.61